# Using "check" icon in a table cell

Tags: jquery-mobile

In a particular table cell, I dont want text, I want the nice "check" icon instead. I've tried all kinds of crazy elements and tried to specify data-icon but no luck.  I'm sure this is easy.

Comment: and what does it have to do with jquery?

Comment: I'm using jquery-mobile and on other elements I can add "data-icon='home'" (or similar).  Trying to do the same on something/anything in a table cell..

Comment: ✔ Do you mean this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo of using the built in jQM icons in a table cell: **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Cj5rg/1/**

Just use the existing CSS classes that set the background to the included images:

```
<span class="ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-icon-shadow"></span></span>
```